PowerSync Sync Rule Issue with Supabase Auth & Relationship Data
I'm transitioning from MongoDB Atlas to PowerSync and Supabase for offline-first capabilities in my app. However, I've encountered a challenge with relationship-based data synchronization.
Here's my setup:

I'm using a Supabase auth hook to update the user's JWT token with app_metadata containing a data key.
This key stores lists of IDs for specific tables (e.g., table_name_ids).
I'm aiming to create a sync rule that utilizes these IDs to filter data based on user access.
The Issue:

Unfortunately, I discovered that PowerSync doesn't directly support JOIN operations in its data queries within the data section of sync rules.
Given PowerSync's limitations with JOINs, I'd appreciate insights on alternative approaches for achieving relationship-based data synchronization in this scenario. Are there recommended strategies to filter data based on user-specific IDs stored in the app_metadata?
Thank you in advance for any guidance!
My Sync Rule (unable to execute):
YAML
bucket_definitions:
  lists:
    parameters: SELECT request.jwt() ->> 'app_metadata.data.table_name_ids' as table_name_ids
    data:
      - SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id IN (bucket.table_name_ids)

The output online rule editor is complaining with some limitations about IN in data queries.

Looks like this question has been answered on the PowerSync Discord. In general, it is a good idea to ask on the Discord
